# SQLite database with JOIN and SELECT

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database problem where basically one course can have many modules AND these modules could be on every single course. So Course 1 could contain module 1 and module 2 but course 2 might only contain module 2. I am hoping to use JSON in the modules table to store timetabling information.

I want to be able to get a list of modules on each course.

What I would want to do is SELECT * from modules where moduleID in (select moduleIDs from courses where courseName = USERSPECIFEDCOURSE)

I want this to return all of the rows in modules table where their ID is matching with the course the user has picked
What will this return, is there a better way of doing this?

[image: db]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is a many-to-many relation between tbl_modules and tbl_Courses, you should remove your moduleIDS column and create a new "relation" table:

tbl_module_course_relations:

```
courseName             moduleID
Cpting with games      1
Cpting with games      2
Cpting                 1
```

your query would become:

```
SELECT * from modules where moduleID in (select moduleID from tbl_module_course_relations where courseName = USERSPECIFEDCOURSE);
```

Actually it would be better to add "id" columns in each table and rely on it for the "relation" table and the foreign keys.

tbl_courses:

```
courseID   courseName
1          Cpting with games
2          Cpting
```

tbl_module_course_relations:

```
courseID             moduleID
1                    1
1                    2
2                    1
```

and the query:

```
SELECT * from modules where moduleID in (select tbl_module_course_relations.moduleID from tbl_module_course_relations, courses where tbl_module_course_relations.courseID = courses.courseID and courses.courseName = USERSPECIFEDCOURSE);
```